# Not able to get form data using getelementbyId from Html to JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am just beginning with programming and starting with `javascript`. I am not able to get a form filled in `html` and get it into `javascript` by `getElementById`. Could you please take a look at my code and tell me a solution.

***HTML form***

```html
input type="text" id="myText"
input type="submit" id="submit"
```

***javascript***

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: remove `id="submit"`- that is what is breaking it.

Comment: you have two id attributes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you put some value into you input field it should work. Please check the example (https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/abLOzBw):

```js
 var x = document.getElementById("myText").value; console.log(x);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="test" />
```

Of course if you want dynamic value in the input - you have to make it empty and then add some event handler, inside that handler use that code `var x = document.getElementById("myText").value; console.log(x);`